# Como melhorar a inicialização do Desktop no cd /etc/xdg/autostart do Elementary OS 5 Hera?

Tags: capnet-assist

Boa tarde pessoal. Quero melhorar a inicialização do desktop no Elementary OS 5 Hera.

**PS. DESCULPEM A TAG, MAS ISSO É UMA MERDA**!

**Fiz a seguinte mudança que achei num post:**

cd /etc/xdg/autostart

## mv at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled

**Por favor, nesses arquivos listados tem algo que possa fazer para melhorar na inicialização do desktop?**

at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop
com.github.spheras.desktopfolder-autostart.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping-pantheon.desktop
gala-daemon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop
gnome-keyring-gpg-pantheon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard-pantheon.desktop
gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop
gnome-keyring-pkcs11-pantheon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys-pantheon.desktop
gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop
gnome-keyring-secrets-pantheon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse-pantheon.desktop
gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop
gnome-keyring-ssh-pantheon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power-pantheon.desktop
indicator-application.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop
io.elementary.appcenter-daemon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications-pantheon.desktop
io.elementary.calendar-daemon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop
io.elementary.cerbere.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill-pantheon.desktop
io.elementary.desktop.agent-geoclue2-daemon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop
io.elementary.desktop.agent-polkit.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop
io.elementary.dpms-helper.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing-pantheon.desktop
io.elementary.onboarding.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop
io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard-pantheon.desktop
light-locker.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop
nm-applet.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound-pantheon.desktop
nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop
onboard-autostart.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom-pantheon.desktop
onboard-autostart-pantheon.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop
orca-autostart.desktop org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings-pantheon.desktop
orca-autostart-pantheon.desktop pantheon-parental-controls-client.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop plank.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings-pantheon.desktop polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop pulseaudio.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard-pantheon.desktop spice-vdagent.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color-pantheon.desktop user-dirs-update-gtk-pantheon.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.desktop xdg-user-dirs.desktop
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime-pantheon.desktop

Comment: English, please.

Comment: Good afternoon people. I want to improve desktop startup on Elementary OS 5 Hera.

I made the following change to improve the startup of the desktop, I found it in a post, but I saw no difference:

cd /etc/xdg/autostart
mv at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled                                                                          
Please, in these listed files, is there anything you can do to improve desktop startup?